# How to move from one controller to next in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a small asp.net mvc application, where I have few actionlinks in my **Index.html** and following code in **home controllder**.

When user click on **Edit ActionLink**, it takes the control to HomerController's "Edit" acton method (which is of type httpGet). The view for that action method is Edit.cshtml. If I do some data manipulation in that EDIT view..and try to POST that data, What should I do ? Write another Edit action method (httpPost) in same HomeController? In that case my home controller will grow bigger right?

If I need to write seperate controller for this purpose, how do I transfer the control to that controller? ( I mean how do I attach my newly created Edit controller to Edit view ?)

```
List<StateCity> stateCityList = new List<StateCity>();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            StateCity sc1 = new StateCity() { Id = 1, StateName = "Dallas", Cities = new List<string>() { "ab", "cd" } };
            StateCity sc2 = new StateCity() { Id = 2, StateName = "Austin", Cities = new List<string>() { "ef", "gh" } };
            stateCityList.Add(sc1);
            stateCityList.Add(sc2);
            return View(stateCityList);
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was told already, add one more action with `HttpPost` attribute and your ViewModel as parameter.

Your controller won't grow if you will follow SRP principle. In my opinion HomeController shouldn't have such actions like Edit. I would move them to corresponding Controller (for example ArticleController). But HomeController would have actions like Index, About.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Article", "Edit", "Article", new { id= 587 }, new { id = "linkId" })
```

Take a look here for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: What I dont know is how do I have another controller and and navigate to that from a link in Index.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Action for HTTP POST using attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(parameters here){}
```

Here is a nice [example of forms in MVC](http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/)

Answer (score 0):

Typically for an edit you'd have two actions.

One for loading the edit page:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

And one for submitting the form (performing the edit):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(YourModel model)
```

If you're concerned that your controller methods are getting too large, consider abstracting the logic/saving code in another layer of your application.